# SQL try catch never gets to catch(implement timeout?)

Tags: java

In my code I have a try catch at the SQL connection part. I want the user to be able to input the Sql address and port number himself. If the user enters the wrong sql address or port, the application just hangs up inside try, and never actually stops and gets to the catch. Any tips? I would like to program to try for X seconds, then end with an error message like "wrong connection information entered".

This is the code:

```
System.out.print("Connecting");

    try {
        String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";

        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://"+mySqlAdress+":"+myPort+"/mysql";
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "1234");
         String SQL = "SELECT asd,val FROM test";
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
           while (rs.next()) {
           //do something
        }
    } 
  catch (Exception e)
 {

  System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add a connection timeout by yourself by invoking [`DriverManager#setLoginTimeout(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#setLoginTimeout%28int%29) before to try to connect.

In the same spirit, notice there is [`Statement#setQueryTimeout(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout%28int%29) that can be called on any kind of SQL statement (be them `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`).

Comment: I added it before the Conncetion conn line, but didn't help ? :( Did some googling and it appers that setLoginTimeout aren't compatible with mysql.

Comment: Strange ... I have no better idea, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Can you try;

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

```
connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/youradress?"
              + "user=youruser&password=yourpassword");
```

Comment: I tried it, still when the address is wrong it is stuck at "Connecting"

Comment: Change your .getConnection usage like that.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood, I can get the SQL to connect without problems, but if the user enters the wrong connection info - then it's stuck at connecting.